# Open GL ubuntu build error

Tags: opengl

I am trying to do something with Ogre and Opengl. I find code in the internet and now I want to use it but I have this problem:

I use this two lines:

```
HGLRC ogreHGLRC; 
HDC ogreHDC;
```

and I have build errors:

```
1. error: ‘ogreHGLRC’ was not declared in this scope
2. error: ‘ogreHDC’ was not declared in this scope
```

I understood that these I can use in Windows but I have Ubuntu.
What do I have to do?

Answer (score 2):

HDC and HGLRC are windows structures defined in windows.h. As long as you're running on linux, you should look at tutorials involving linux.

If you have enough experience, you can start up OGRE with glx. But I recommend using OGREApplication class (not sure about the name of the class, you can download it with ogre samples)

Also look at here: http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/Setting+Up+An+Application+-+Linux&structure=Development

Comment: Yes my friend. But I want to use QT library and the example I found have HDC and HGLRC... And I cant do anything...

Comment: @user1189457: Well, I suspect that those tutorials were about creating a PBuffer or sharing contexts, because that's the only reason I see to go down to the system dependent APIs. I'm pretty sure that what you want to do, can be done without them very well.